# Dynamically add rows to columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding rows dynamically to a table. The table already has a row consisting of column headers like date, day etc.

```
for(var i=0; i<=fix;i++){
var cols = 5;
var tr = $('<tr>');
$('<td name=Date"+i+" id=Date_"+i+"></td>').appendTo(tr);
$('<td id=day_"+ i+">"+theday +"</td>').appendTo(tr);
for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++){
$('<td> <input type=text name=value_"+i+" id=value"+i+"></td>').appendTo(tr);
      }
tr.appendTo($('#tbl> tbody:first'))
}
```

I want to fill the 'td's with some vlaues stored in variable. But if i write

```
$('<td name=Date"+i+" id=Date_"+i+">"+var+"</td>').appendTo(tr);
```

where var is a variable, Its value does not appear. Instead the whole string is displayed. How can i prefill then with some variable values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
$("<td name='Date"+i+"' id='Date_"+i+"'>"+your_var+"</td>").appendTo(tr);
```

Comment: Thnks for your answer. I have few more doubt. Can i add style here. And can i clear  all the rows except the column header row? I mean if any more row exists apart from the column header at the beginning, then i want to clear them. Is it posible?

Answer (score 0):

Your `i` is being treated as a letter, not as a variable. Use proper quotes:

```
$('<td name=Date"' + i + '" id=Date_"' + i + '">"' + rename_me_please + '"</td>').appendTo(tr);
```

Also, rename `var` to something else. `var` is a reserved keyword.